# Excel - Split Data by certain number of rows and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a macro on Excel that would help achieve the following:

I have about 300k lines of data in one column (column A). I need to copy data and transpose where the delimiter is each 4 rows. I hope it makes sense.

This is an example input (left) and output (right).

https://gyazo.com/ae8dd04182e28140814f386241bc8255

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$999,ROWS(E$2:E2)*4-4+COLUMNS($E2:E2))
```

Please change the range as per your data.

[**Demo**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IR8t6-XM4nkExoBh1ltPG5s9bKy0dy3bDHZAHfnNhaE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm. I was trying to write a macro, but I wasn't getting anywhere.